# How to Deactivate a row in mysql instead of Deleting

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can I deactivate a row instead of deleting it, using flag values in MySQL?

Comment: what u have done so far??

Comment: you just add a column and assign flag on or off (0/1) for on and off

Answer (score 2):

Add an `active` column to the table, and then do:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET active = 0
WHERE id = :id
```

to deactivate the row. You'll then need to update all other queries so they do:

```
WHERE active = 1
```

There's no built-in mechanism that does this automatically.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to include columns like this in any relevant indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column in your table as type `CHARACTER(1)`, and use something like `'A'` for active and `'D'` for deactivated.

There isn't a "flag value" for mysql, people refer to it as a flag, as they created the flag within their own tables for use as such.